# How to copy content inside of a txt file to clipboard?

Tags: python, file-io, clipboard

I have a txt file on my Desktop: test.txt. I want to open that txt file and copy everything to the clipboard.

How do I do it?

I figured how to open file and read lines:

```
path = 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test.txt'

fo = open(path, 'r').readlines()
```

But I can't figure out how to get that data into the clipboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using [Pyperclip](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/)

```
import pyperclip
fo = open(path, 'r').read()
pyperclip.copy(fo)
```

If you're on OS X, you can also try this code:

```
import os 
data = "hello world"
os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % data)
```

Comment: How do I make python to read all content inside of text file and copy it with pyperclip. I know pyperclip can copy whats inside of arguments like this: pyperclip.copy('text') but how do I make it copy whole content from text file?

Comment: @Towelie Did you try like this 'fo = open(path, 'r').read()'

Comment: read it into a variable and use the variable as an argument: 
`fo = open(path, 'r').readlines()
pyperclicp.copy(fo)`

Comment: I tried that, it gives me error

Comment: feel free to post it

Comment: ctypes.memmove(c_wchar_p(locked_handle), c_wchar_p(text), count * sizeof(c_wchar))

TypeError: unicode string or integer address expected instead of list instance

Comment: right, use read() instead of readlines()

Comment: It works perfectly now, thanks bro : )

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer, so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

use pyperclip. It's crossplatform.