# How do I copy lines from a text file onto the clipboard in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that i want to copy from line by line and paste into a webpage, how would i go about this?

I have no code so far, I can only find things about copying the actual file itself and copying lines into another file

This is my 3rd day learning python so you might need to do some extra explaining lol.

Comment: What do you mean by "*paste into a webpage*"? As in manually, not using Python, using the standard "Ctrl+V" or right-click+paste? For the part about copying the file contents into the clipboard, see [How to copy content inside of a txt file to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36391824/2745495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have pip, you can install a module called `pyperclip`.

On macOS:

`pip3 install pyperclip` (sometimes add `--user` onto the end)

On Windows:

`pip install pyperclip`

Now that you have this installed, you need to read the file with `file.read()` and store it into a variable, then call `pyperclip.copy(variablename)`.

Full code:

```
import pyperclip

with open("path/to/file.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    pyperclip.copy(data)
```

Comment: thanks for answering! will this copy everything or just one line?

Comment: It will copy everything.